# How to stand up local HDFS for unit/integration testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hadoop, integration-testing, hdfs

I am looking for a way to automatically (within a test class) stand up, configure, then shut down a local HDFS instance to do unit/integration testing. I am using the webhdfs (and in the future, httpfs) interface to write/read/delete files from hdfs.

Comment: OMG that sounds like a nightmare.  FYI for "unit" tests you want them to run fast, so this would no way be a unit test.  It would be easier to just have an integrations test suite that is run via a jenkins job on a test cluster. Or even your production cluster if you have your user groups sorted nicely.